# The width of my Web page is 1680px. No matter how big the resolution of the other monitors is let the width of my Web page be same as 1680 px

Tags: javascript, jquery

The width of my Web page is 1680px. No matter how big the resolution of the other monitors is (1920px, 2560px, 2880px,...), let the width of my Web page be same as 1680 px.  I tried to make it by using "iframe", but problems occur. How can I do it using Jquery?

[image]

Comment: I think your manager shouted "make it hard 1680px!", because a frontend-developer will never do this :). Maybe think about using max-width.

Answer (score 1):

don't understand why you want do that but :

You can create a container on your body

```
<body>
  <div class="container">
      <!-- your page -->
  </div>
</body>
```

and set the width to 1680px in css...

```
.container{
width:1680px;
margin:0 auto;
}
```